# Update nav menu not selecting parent

Tags: menus

I am building a nav menu programmatically like so:

```
$menu_exists = wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'test_menu' );
if( !$menu_exists){
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu('test_menu');
    buildMenu($menuArray,$menu_id);
}

function buildMenu($array,$menu_id) {

    foreach ($array as $menu) {

        var_dump( wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => $menu[0]->post_title,
            'menu-item-object' => 'page',
            'menu-item-object-id' => $menu[0]->ID,
            'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            'menu-item-parent-id' => $menu[0]->post_parent)));


        if(!empty($menu[1])) {
            buildMenu($menu[1],$menu_id);
        }
    }

}
```

Where `$menuArray` is collection of post objects.  This is working, however all the menus items get added to the top level and the `menu-item-parent-id` is ignored.  Does WordPress expect the `menu-item-parent-id` to be the nav menu id or the post id?

Comment: Can you show us the `$menuArray` value? At least a sample non-working `$menuArray` value.

Comment: @cybmeta its just a collection of post objects.  The array its self is working fine, the only problem is the items are not nesting to their parents.

Comment: Well, I need it to look for a possible problem and its solution, if you don't provide it I can not reproduce the issue.

Comment: @cybmeta added example

Comment: I can not see the example and the example you added before was not useful. Anyway, I think that `menu-item-parent-id` needs a ID of an already menu item id.

Comment: @cybmeta Yes, I removed it because it wasn't useful and your correct, the `menu-item-parent-id` takes the `menu-item-id` not the `post-id`.

Answer (score 0):

As I originally suspected, `menu-item-parent-id` takes the id of the menu item and not the id of the parent page.

So I referenced the menu item ID and passed it into the recursive function :

```
function buildMenu( $array, $menu_id, $parent_id = false ) {

    foreach ($array as $menu) {

        $menuItemId = wp_update_nav_menu_item(
            $menu_id,
            0,
            array(
                'menu-item-title'     => $menu[0]->post_title,
                'menu-item-object'    => 'page',
                'menu-item-object-id' => $menu[0]->ID,
                'menu-item-type'      => 'post_type',
                'menu-item-status'    => 'publish',
                'menu-item-parent-id' => $parent_id
            )
        );


        if(!empty($menu[1])) {
            buildMenu( $menu[1], $menu_id, $menuItemId );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to fix some typo erros and to add `$parent_id` to the `buildMenu` function. I'd still like to see what `$array` is, so then we can know what is `$menu[1]` and know what this code exactly does.